# Is it necessary to add "had" in past tense narration when it's clear we're talking about the past?

Tags: style, narrative

Example:

> Standing in front of the sliding glass door, he began to sweat. The
> last time **he had stepped into a convenience store was a year ago.**

This is past tense narration. The **bolded** part is talking about the past within that past tense narration.

It states that the event happened a year ago, so is it necessary to include *had*? Why or why not?

Comment: Despite appearances, I suggest this is a Question not about writing but about basic English grammar, which will dredge up subsidiaries such as whether that example shouldn't really say "The last time he had stepped into a convenience store had been a year ago."

For reasons like that, I suggest you ask the same thing in SE English Language Learning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you’ve written it, I think *had* is necessary.  It reads off without it.

But re-arranging things, it's not needed.

> Standing in front of the sliding glass door, sweating, he remembered last year and stepping into a convenience store.

And, now the statement has some suspense to it. \o/!

I’ve had this argument with another writer, who insists that *had* needs to be used in past tense sentences to avoid the confusion of simultaneous actions. I found it pedantic, and didn’t like how it changed my writing.

For me, I only use had if the sentence needs it to sound right, or if I need to be very clear about the order of events or actions or reaction in a sentence.  If a sentence sounds okay without had, and its meaning clear, I avoid using it since its a kind of hard sounding word that throws my rhythms off

Comment: You can also avoid ambiguity with something like "The previous time he stepped into a convenience store was a year earlier"

Comment: Your adaption completely changes the meaning of the sentence. I don't think it's correct. In your version, the character goes into the store, in the original version, we only know that he did so last year but in the present, he may decide against it.

Comment: @Barmar, I don't think your version changes the grammar. You replaced "The last time" with "The previous time" and "a year ago" with "a year earlier". You also could decide to insert "had" in your version of the sentence. I don't see how it resolves the question of whether or not "had" is necessary.

Comment: Yes, you can use "had", but it's no longer necessary to indicate that you're talking about time further in the past from the existing context.

Comment: I prefer the original example so much more. The rewording is totally different, and a little unusual (perhaps just to me). The original is dramatic, cliché/idiomatic, and really definitively sets the scene and conveys the palpable feelings of fear the character is experiencing.

Comment: @Barmar "the previous time" does not mean the same as "the last time". "The previous time" implies there was only *one* "previous" event.

Comment: I disagree that "had" is required, though it's harmless (if you don't mind using more words than you need to).

Comment: @alephzero I disagree. The difference between "the last" and "the previous" is whether it's relative to "now" or the time being referenced in the narration. Neither implies "only one".

Answer (score 12):

"Had" changes the meaning slightly:

> The last time he had stepped into a convenience store was a year ago.

He hasn't stepped into a store between *that moment* and a year before.

> The last time he stepped into a convenience store was a year ago.

He hasn't stepped into a store between *now* and a year before. This will not be true if he goes through the door.

Comment: Not super sure about this. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Maybe this would be true if we consider "had" vs "has"?

Comment: This is correct.  However, *now* can be the current place in the story (especially if it's in the character's thoughts), so depending on the context, either could be acceptable.

Comment: You might change the first one to read "Until today, ..." that would make your answer clearer

Comment: This is _technically_  correct, but I guess lots of readers (like myself) will just skim over it and interpret both in the same way (in the "had" sense). However, "had" should be included anyway because it sounds better too. Its omission would be unnatural and suspicious.

Comment: I think in the *between X and Y*, the more important change brought on by using *had* is the change in *Y*.  One is "between that moment and *a year prior to that moment*", the other is "between now and *a year prior to now*".  Removal of *had* completely changes the meaning of *a year ago*.

Answer (score 7):

In the present context, it's not necessary to include 'had' in the sentence. Using 'had' would indicate the past perfect (pluperfect) tense, which is used for conveying a sequence of events. The simple perfect just conveys that an event occurred in the past. Either is a reasonable reading of your sentence. You can read more [about past perfect here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/).

Comment: The first sentence is already in the past, so presumably the past-in-the-past would be appropriate, no?